# Combine 2 arrays simply in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

No consider same keys, only join an array to another.

```
Array(0 => 'aaa', 1 => 'bbb');
Array(1 => 'ccc', 2 => 'ddd');
```

I hope the result:

```
Array(0 => 'aaa', 1 => 'bbb', 2 => 'ccc', 3 => 'ddd');
```

I do not want to write a function to join them. Is there any PHP function available for it?

Comment: Yes, there is a function for that. Did you try [looking in the PHP reference](http://php.net/array_merge)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
<?php
   $array1 = Array(0 => 'aaa', 1 => 'bbb');
   $array2 = Array(1 => 'ccc', 2 => 'ddd');
   $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
   print_r($result);
?>
```